# How to attach an image to loaded object in Three.js

Tags: three.js

I'm trying to attach a custom image to an object (.obj)

What I want is

[image]

But the result is

[image]

I want the image to be located in the center of the object for only one time. But the image is repeated to fill the entire material.

I googled a lot and read some articles about uv mapping but I could not figure out how to apply to a custom object.

Following is my code. Thanks in advance.

```
var mtlLoader = new MTLLoader();
    mtlLoader.load("~~~.mtl", function (materials) {
      materials.preload();

      var objLoader = new THREE.OBJLoader();
      objLoader.setMaterials(materials);
      objLoader.load( 
        "~~.obj",
        function (geometry) {
          var textureLoader = new THREE.TextureLoader();
          var texture = textureLoader.load("~~.jpg");
          var material = new THREE.MeshLambertMaterial({
            transparent: true,
            map: texture, // <- ??
          });
          texture.minFilter = THREE.LinearFilter;
          texture.wrapS = texture.wrapT = THREE.ClampToEdgeWrapping;

          geometry.traverse(function (child) {
            if (child instanceof THREE.Mesh) {
              child.material = material; 
            }
          });
          scene.add(geometry);
        }
```

Comment: The problem is not in your code. You were on the right track, the issue is with the `uv` mapping of your model. The only way to get the texture to show up only on its torso is to open the model in a 3D editor [like Blender](https://www.blender.org/), look at how the UVs have been mapped, and update them to suit your needs. Or you could separate the torso from the rest of the body so the texture only affects one and not the other. Either way, this is an asset-creation problem that will need a 3D editor.

Comment: @Marquizzo Thanks for the comment. I want user to add custom image to the certain part of the object. Is there any way to implement it inside the three.js front-end without editing the object in a 3D editor?

Comment: I don't see how it could be done. You can manually update the `uv` attributes via code, yes, but then you'd need to write an algorithm that would map the `uvs` onto the desired projection. That's the difficult part that would be much, much easier on a 3D editor.